# AngularJS Directive Not Showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This has completely driven me up the wall for hours now.

I have my app.js

```
    'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name myWellnessTrackerApp
 * @description
 * # myWellnessTrackerApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('myWellnessTrackerApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

My main.html which is loaded into the main page on load as shown above.

```
<innerPageHeader> </innerPageHeader>
```

My directive.

```
angular.module('myWellnessTrackerApp')
  .directive('innerPageHeader' ,function () {
    return {
      template: '<h4>TEST</h4>',
      restrict: 'E'
    };
  });
```

And my index.html scritps:

```
<!-- build:js(**/*) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="components/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="components/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="components/foundation/js/foundation.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/innerpageheader.js"></script>
```

When loading the page it just shows

```
<innerPageHeader> </innerPageHeader>
```

With no directive content which should be

```
<innerPageHeader><h4>TEST</h4> </innerPageHeader>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the directive as follows.

```
<inner-page-header></inner-page-header>
```

Comment: Works, Which is very ANNOYING :(

Can you tell me why it must be name-name-name when the name is just nameNameName ?

Comment: I am not aware of a definitive explanation for why it has been done this way. Although it does seem to be the convention for html/xml documents.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you've already figured this out but the reason is because of normalization. During normalization, Angular converts - delimited name to camelCase.

This is why you should use camelCase while specifying the directive inside AngularJS.